# AJAX HTTP Basic Authentication Workaround

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, authentication

I'm working on an RESTful API for use with a JavaScript client. All API calls are authenticated. Unfortunately, in the event of incorrect credentials being provided the dreadful browser prompt pops up.

Now, I'm aware that there is no way to suppress this on the client side. Fortunately, I'm in control of both the client and the API.

I'd like to keep the API as canon as possible. So I'd rather not change the response code to 403. As an alternative I'm considering allowing the client to suppress the WWW-Authenticate header (via a custom header in the request). It appears that it is that that triggers the prompt and not necessarily the 401 code itself at least in the latest version of Chrome.

Does anyone have any insight on that? Is it reliable in other browsers? Any reasons why I shouldn't go this route?

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 0):

The popup is a `401 Unauthorized` answer, and if you are using jQuery you can catch that either in the `error()` callback, or in the `statusCode` property of the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : 'GET/POST/PUT/DELETE',
    data : { your data here },
    dataType : 'json/xml/html',
    statusCode : {

        200 : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

            // your logic here

        },                                  

        401 : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            // your logic here

        }

    }

});
```

If you need to perform any edits on request header, use `beforeSend()` callback in the call so you can inject / remove stuff before it is executed.

Comment: Are you suggesting that by catching it I can stop it from displaying?

Comment: @KTastrophy my bad, I tried on my own and 401 dialog appears in ajax call as well - so you may suppress the `WWW-Authenticate header` when answering to a XHR.